# cómo desactivo un link al dar click sobre el

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

quiero que al dar click en el enlace este desaparezca, ya que hace la funcion de mostrar contenido y no quiero repetirlo.

```
<p>mira la respuesta(<a href="#" class="alternar-respuesta">ver respuesta</a>)</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más sencilla que se me ocurre es usar las etiquetas [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) y [summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary):

```css
details.respuesta summary {
    cursor: pointer;
}
details.respuesta[open] summary {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<details class="respuesta">
    <summary>Ver respuesta</summary>
    <p>Aqui va la respuesta</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<p>mira la respuesta(<a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="alternar-respuesta">ver respuesta</a>)</p>

<p>mira la respuesta(<a href="#" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';" class="alternar-respuesta">ver respuesta</a>)</p>
```